# How to save the current model when ajax is requesting?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using Ajax in my application to update a view without refresh the webpage.

Can you notice here http://contoso2.azurewebsites.net/Test/DoTest because I'm highlighting the partial view in yellow color.

But the problem is, when I enter data to the items (math problem), when Ajax is requesting, I don't see the changes in the model.

```
    public ActionResult DoTest()
    {
        List<Worksheet> worksheets = null;

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            worksheets = Session["Worksheets"] as List<Worksheet>;
            return PartialView("_Problems", worksheets[1]);
        }

        worksheets = new List<Worksheet>()
        {
            new Worksheet("Addition and Subtraction of absolute values", new List<Problem1>() { ... }),
            new Worksheet("Addition and Subtraction of absolute values", new List<Problem1>() { ... })
        }

        Session["Worksheets"] = worksheets;
        return View(worksheets[0]);
    }
```

I'm using a `Session` to recover my model, but if I debug in it I don't see any changes of the models. How can I do for when I press continue button, my model updates.

EDIT: This contain my AJAX in razor view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "get",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "problemList"
    }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
}
```

Comment: Why dont you break the calls into two actions. One will be a Get Action rendering the View and another be a POST action acting on the response of the end user. the Post action can have a parameter List<Worksheet>, ASP.NET ModelBinder will take care of the rest!

Comment: @frictionlesspulley The first part I understand. Can you show an example to guide me? I'm not too experienced in MVC and I don't have idea how to pass the parameter List<Worksheet> through Http

Comment: It seems like you're only doing a get here, not posting the existing data back to the server.  Are you expecting it to update the data stored in the session on each get?

Comment: I guess the session does not make sense if I'm gonna do this through post.. that was my first option

Comment: Have you tried returning an array? return View(worksheets[0]).toArray();

Answer (score 2):

I usually have two Actions for a View . Though this is not a mandatory requirement.

The first action decorated with `HttpGet` renders the page on a Get when the user comes to the page for the first time. the second action is invoked when the user clicks next and posts a form.

```
public class TestController {

   [HttpGet]
   public void DoTest(){

        var viewModel = new List<Worksheet>()
        {
            new Worksheet("Addition and Subtraction of absolute values", new List<Problem1>() { ... }),
            new Worksheet("Addition and Subtraction of absolute values", new List<Problem1>() { ... })
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

   [HttpPost]
   public void DoTest(List<Worksheet> worksheets){

        //do whatever you want with the user response

        var response =  worksheets[1]; 
        PartialView("_Problems",responseModel);
    }
}
```

Note : you will have to invoke the ajax call with `HttpMethod = "post"`. The ModelBinder in ASP.NET will bind the values posted in the request to your responseModel `worksheets`

You should try and go over the "getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4" tutorials available on http://asp.net/

Comment: I undertand!! I like it!! Just one doubt, when I press the submit button, it doesn't access to the HTTPPost method, do I need to specify some routeValue when I post?

Comment: are u invoking the ajax call using HttpMethod = "Post" ?

Comment: Yes, now it accessing to it.. now with I'm dealing is when I receive my list, the value is null

Comment: make sure that the Model has a default constructor and you are sending the Named Parameters correctly

Comment: No no, I mean, when I debug the variable worksheets has 0 elements.. and that's so rare because I can see the data when is a HTTPGET